# How to change the nuxt gmap marker icon size?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, google-maps-markers

I added the marker like this.How can I shrink the png I have added to the Marker?

```
     <GMap
    v-if="car"
    ref="gMap"
    :center="{ lat: car.data.posLatitude, lng: car.data.posLongitude }"
    :zoom="6"
  >
    <GMapMarker
      :position="{
        lat: this.geolocation.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        lng: this.geolocation.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
      }"
      :options="{ icon: require('../../../assets/home.png') }"
    >
    </GMapMarker>

    <GMapMarker
      :position="{ lat: car.data.posLatitude, lng: car.data.posLongitude }"
      :options="{ icon: require('../../../assets/car.png') }"
    >
    </GMapMarker>
  </GMap>
```

[screenshot like this. I want to shrink the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kAP2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `GMapMarker` component handle your actual icon image rendering, you can manipulate it like so:

```js
var icon = {
    url: "../res/sit_marron.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

<GMapMarker :icon="icon"></GMapMarker>
```

then inside your GMapMarker component, you can render it like so:

```js
// grab icon from the props and use it as needed:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```

More info here in official docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex#maps_icon_complex-javascript